# How can I check the syntax of Python code in Emacs without actually executing it?

Tags: python, validation, emacs, syntax

Python's IDLE has 'Check Module' (Alt-X) to check the syntax which can be called without needing to run the code. Is there an equivalent way to do this in Emacs instead of running and executing the code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can [use Pyflakes together with Flymake](https://web.archive.org/web/20090503090851/http://www.plope.org/Members/chrism/flymake-mode) in order to get instant notification when your python code is valid (and avoids a few common pitfalls as well).

Comment: The domain `plope.org` in this URL does not exist anymore, hence the documentation is not anymore available.

Comment: I updated it to an archive.org version. Hopefully this gets you the info you need :)

Comment: Yes but even better is to copy here the relevant stuff.

Answer (score 18):

```
python -m py_compile script.py
```

Answer (score 2):

Or from emacs (or vim) you could run `python -c 'import x'` where x is the name of your file minus the `.py` extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pylint](http://www.logilab.org/857) for such things and there seems to be a way to integrate it into [emacs](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/PythonMode#toc8), but I've never done the latter b/c I'm a vim user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pylint, pychecker, pyflakes etc. from Emacs' `compile` command (`M-x compile`).

Hint: bind a key (say, F5) to `recompile`.